# What is the length of ciphertext for AES encryption using C#?

Tags: encryption, aes

From:
[Can we calculate AES ciphertext length based on the length of the plaintext?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54017/can-we-calculate-aes-ciphertext-length-based-on-the-length-of-the-plaintext?newreg=1ce930f3fa664ef3a5c17da4d32462b4)

I see:  output_size = input_size + (16 - (input_size % 16))

But this does not seem to correspond with what I see when running tests using C# and the AesCng with PKCS7 padding and CBC CipherMode.

Thoughts on how I calculate the length of the encrypted value?

Here's the code for sample program:

```
Public Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal aes256BitKeyValue As String, ByVal initialVector As String) As String

  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText) Then
    Return String.Empty
  End If

  Dim initialVectorBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initialVector)
  Dim plainTextBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText)
  Dim cipherTextBytes As Byte() = Nothing

  Using symmetricKey As New System.Security.Cryptography.AesCng()
    symmetricKey.Padding = Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.PKCS7
    symmetricKey.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC

    Dim keyBytes As Byte() = StringToByteArray(aes256BitKeyValue)

    Try

      Using cryptographyTransform As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initialVectorBytes)
        Using memoryStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
          Using cryptographyStream As New System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptographyTransform, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            cryptographyStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length)
            cryptographyStream.FlushFinalBlock()
            cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray()
            memoryStream.Close()
            cryptographyStream.Close()
          End Using
        End Using
      End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
      Throw New Exceptions.EncryptionException(String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Resources.ExceptionMessages.EncryptionFailed1, ex))

    Finally
      symmetricKey.Clear()
    End Try

  End Using

  Return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes)

End Function
```

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string aes256Key = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234";
      string initialVector = "66sDeG*3xsS334dE";

```
  string unencrypted20Text = "12345678901234567890";
  string unencrypted40Text = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
  string unencrypted64Text = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234";
  string unencrypted128Text = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678";
  string unencrypted256Text = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456";
  string unencrypted257Text = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567";
  string unencrypted512Text = unencrypted256Text + unencrypted256Text;
  string unencrypted1024Text = unencrypted512Text + unencrypted512Text;
  string unencrypted2048Text = unencrypted1024Text + unencrypted1024Text;
  string unencrypted4096Text = unencrypted2048Text + unencrypted2048Text;
  string unencrypted8192Text = unencrypted4096Text + unencrypted4096Text;

  string encrypted20Text = Grb.Core.Cryptography.AesEncryption.Encrypt(unencrypted20Text, aes256Key, initialVector);
  string encrypted40Text = Grb.Core.Cryptography.AesEncryption.Encrypt(unencrypted40Text, aes256Key, initialVector);
  string encrypted64Text = Grb.Core.Cryptography.AesEncryption.Encrypt(unencrypted64Text, aes256Key, initialVector);
  string encrypted128Text = Grb.Core.Cryptography.AesEncryption.Encrypt(unencrypted128Text, aes256Key, initialVector);
  string encrypted256Text = Grb.Core.Cryptography.AesEncryption.Encrypt(unencrypted256Text, aes256Key, initialVector);
  string encrypted257Text = Grb.Core.Cryptography.AesEncryption.Encrypt(unencrypted257Text, aes256Key, initialVector);
  string encrypted512Text = Grb.Core.Cryptography.AesEncryption.Encrypt(unencrypted512Text, aes256Key, initialVector);
  string encrypted1024Text = Grb.Core.Cryptography.AesEncryption.Encrypt(unencrypted1024Text, aes256Key, initialVector);
  string encrypted2048Text = Grb.Core.Cryptography.AesEncryption.Encrypt(unencrypted2048Text, aes256Key, initialVector);
  string encrypted4096Text = Grb.Core.Cryptography.AesEncryption.Encrypt(unencrypted4096Text, aes256Key, initialVector);
  string encrypted8192Text = Grb.Core.Cryptography.AesEncryption.Encrypt(unencrypted8192Text, aes256Key, initialVector);

  int encrypted20TextLength = encrypted20Text.Length; // actual: 44, expected 20 + (16 - 4) = 32
  int encrypted40TextLength = encrypted40Text.Length; // actual: 64, expected 40 + (116 - 8) = 48
  int encrypted64TextLength = encrypted64Text.Length; // actual: 108, expected 64 + (16 - 0) = 80
  int encrypted128TextLength = encrypted128Text.Length; // actual: 192, expected 128 + (16 - 0) = 144
  int encrypted256TextLength = encrypted256Text.Length; // actual: 364 
  int encrypted257TextLength = encrypted257Text.Length; // actual: 364
  int encrypted512TextLength = encrypted512Text.Length; // actual: 704
  int encrypted1024TextLength = encrypted1024Text.Length; // actual: 1388
  int encrypted2048TextLength = encrypted2048Text.Length; // actual: 2752
  int encrypted4096TextLength = encrypted4096Text.Length; // actual: 5484
  int encrypted8192TextLength = encrypted8192Text.Length; // actual: 10944



}
```

}
}

Comment: Note the end of the source code where the "actual" is listed (as seen in the debugger in visual studio) -vs- the expected.  The problem is the actual and expected seem to be different.

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - This appears to be a question about programming; programming questions are off-topic here and belong on stackoverflow (even if they are using cryptography). stackoverflow will probably require you to modify your code snippet to use the minimal amount of code that will reproduce the result you have a question about.

Comment: You're converting to (traditional i.e. nontrimmed) **base64**. Base64 of 32 bytes is ceil(32/3)*4=44 chars.  Base64 of 48 bytes is 64 chars. Base64 of 80 bytes is 108 chars. <brynner> Et cetera, et cetera, et cetera </> This doesn't really have anything to do with crypto, just data in computers.